# My webPage can't start

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I tried to uncheck the 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process', which is under the debug tab and i closed and open the visual studio but it still can't work. Furthermore, i am also running the webpage in Administrator mode.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebPage1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
        }

        public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        public void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        public void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        public void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Stop();
        }

        public void toolStripButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoHome();
        }

        public void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);
                toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(e.MaximumProgress);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigate(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Direct to Google", "Go", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com.sg/");
                Console.WriteLine("Running");
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("run");
            }

        }



        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com.sg/");
           // Console.WriteLine("Running");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com.sg/");
            //Console.WriteLine("Running");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Does solution compile? When the problem appears?

Comment: What do you mean by can't work or can't start. That's too unclear. Be specific and help members by mentioning the error/s that you get or the current behavior.

Comment: i don't received any errors. My webPage just can't run since this morning

Comment: first time i seen that webpage can't run.... i think you need to reinstall

Comment: The code you're showing seems to be a windows forms application hosting a web browser control. As such, neither [tag:asp.net] nor [tag:webforms] seem to be applicable here. Also, you should be aware that you can rename controls - you don't have to leave names like `toolStripButton6` in your code.

Comment: Although you called your namespace `WebPage1` and tagged your question with `asp.net` and `webforms`, your code actually shows a `winforms` application containing a `WebBrowser` control. This is not a web application at all. In case you're trying to "host" this under IIS, it is not going to work at all